# Passing command line arguments to Visual Studio using CMake for profile guided optimization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, release

I'm using `CMake` for a `C++` project. I'm trying to use [`profile guided optimization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/profile-guided-optimizations?view=vs-2017) so I need to also pass command line arguments to the `Release` mode version of my binary. `Visual Studio` needs this to create a performance profile. I already have a `launch.vs.json` configuration for the `Debug` mode binary with command line arguments:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "MyProject",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyProject.exe",
      "type": "default",
      "args": [
        "...", "..."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I switch to `Release` mode and choose the `MyProject` startup item, `Visual Studio` shows the following error message:

```
Unable to start debugging. The startup project could not be launched.
```

Why does it not work that way? I also cannot setup another profile and make `Visual Studio` recognize it in `Release` mode but it works fine in `Debug` mode.

Comment: Probably need to add more context, like your configuration. Could be anything.

Comment: did you try `RelWithDebInfo` instead of release ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it now by adding another entry:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "MyProject",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyProject.exe",
      "type": "default",
      "args": ["...", "..."]
    },
    {
      "name": "MyProject (Release\\MyProject.exe)",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyProject.exe (Release\\MyProject.exe)",
      "type": "default",
      "args": ["...", "..."]
    }
  ]
}
```