# Visual Studio ignoring CMake linker flags for profile guided optimization

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, linker, pgo

I have a `C++` project which uses `CMake` as its build system in `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise`. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/profile-guided-optimizations), I have to link using `/LTCG` and `/GENPROFILE`. In `CMake`, this seems to equate to setting the variable `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`:

```
set(LINKER_FLAGS, "/LTCG /GENPROFILE")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

Furthermore, since my application requires command line arguments, I had to define them in the `launch.vs.json` as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853407/3764804).

Now if I run the application's `x64-Release` profile, it successfully completes in a normal, non-delayed `Release` build fashion. No `.pgd` has been generated which means that my passed linker flags probably have been ignored.

Another try was adding additional `CMake` linker flag variables:

```
set(LINKER_FLAGS, "/LTCG /USEPROFILE")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} ${LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

This also didn't work. Specifying `/USEPROFILE` afterwards did not generate a different binary. Also, the runtimes are roughly equivalent. There is also no indication on the command line that a profile has been generated or used.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When use CMake, forget about comma as a separator... I mean that `set(LINKER_FLAGS, "/LTCG /GENPROFILE")` will assign a variable named `LINKER_FLAGS,` (with comma!).

Comment: Yes, that worked now. Thanks :)
But the optimized executable isn't even faster than the original even though it is fed the same input arguments for the calculation. Oh well, that wasn't useful then.